# Finding the Jordan canonical form when the characteristic polynomial does not split?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

A problem on the 2009 qualifying exam for Harvard is the following:

Suppose $\phi$ is an endomorphism of a 10-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with the following properties:

1. The characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)^4(x^2-3)^3$.
2. The minimal polynomial is $(x-2)^2(x^2-3)^2$.
3. The endomorphism $\phi-2I$, where $I$ is the identity map, is of rank 8.

Find the Jordan canonical form for $\phi$.

Unless I'm missing something about this problem, $\phi$ should not have a Jordan canonical form, right? Not all of its eigenvalues lie in the field $\mathbb{Q}$, so are we done? I guess it feels hard to believe that a qualifying exam problem would be solved this way.

Am I missing something here? Or would you assume that the exam writers wanted us to extend the field to $\mathbb{R}$ and find the Jordan form there?

Comment: From the way I understand the question, the exam writers meant that you have a $10$-by-$10$ matrix with rational coefficients. The Jordan canonical form usually assumes that you are working over $\mathbb{C}$ (though there is a real version which is more complicated). I am guessing they want you to extend the field to $\mathbb{C}$ (or at least to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Basically $2$ has algebraic multiplicity $4$, and since the minimal polynomial has degree $2$ in $(x-2)$, then the maximal size of a Jordan block for $\lambda = 2$ is $2$. But we could have either two $2$-by-$2$ blocks, or one $2$-by-$2$ block and two $1$-by-$1$ blocks. Use the information in property $3$ to rule out one of these two cases. Do the same kind of analysis for the other eigenvalues.

Comment: Op, are you familiar with the construction of the real Jordan canonical form?

Comment: @Malkoun I see, thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @LucaMorstabilini Yes, thanks. I had no problem coming up with the Jordan form following the same logic that Malkoun mentioned. I was just confused on the wording of the problem since there should be no Jordan form over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The Jordan normal form is about eigenvalues, so you cannot avoid $\pm\sqrt{3}$. The question though does not say anything about the Jordan form to be an endomorphism over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Bundle_Time for such a $\phi$ you can construct an "extended" Jordan canonical form akin to the real one, that is a canonical form for $\phi$ which is given by a matrix with only rational coeffiecients -- which i believe is what the exercise asked for, otherwise it is really trivial. I can explain it, if it can interest you.

Comment: @LucaMorstabilini Ah, I believe that a notion of an "extended" Jordan form is exactly what I was looking for. The form I came up with has irrational coefficients, so I would love to see what you mean by one with rational coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we will do is construct a generalization of the real Jordan canonical form. I will mostly omit proofs, since they are simple computations. This will work for any endomorphism $\phi$ over a finite dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $V$ such that the splitting field of the polynomial characteristic of $\phi$ is of degree $2$.
Let $L$ be said extension of $\mathbb{K}$, i.e. $L = \mathbb{K}(\alpha)$. Every element of $L$ can be written as $z = x + \alpha y$, with $x$ and $y \in \mathbb{K}$. In lack of a better notation, since i do not know if there is one, i will use $\text{Re}(z)$ to mean $x$ and $\text{Im}(z)$ for y, and call them respectively real and imaginary part of $z$, taking inspiration from the real and complex numbers. If you know a better one, or a more used one, please let me know.
We consider now the endomorphism $\phi \otimes Id_L$ of $V \otimes_\mathbb{K} L$, and by abuse of notation denote it by $\phi$ again. In the real case, this corresponds to complexification. The important thing is that the matrix representing $\phi$ and $\phi \otimes Id_L$ are the same, and have the same characteristic polynomial (since the matrices are the same) and the same minimal polynomial (see, for example [Minimal polynomial is invariant under field extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578459/minimal-polynomial-is-invariant-under-field-extensions)).

We first note that the spectrum of $\phi$ is the union of the eigenvalues belonging to $\mathbb{K}$ and those belonging to $L \setminus \mathbb{K}$. Those belonging to  $L \setminus \mathbb{K}$ come in "conjugate" pairs, in the sense that if $\mu = a + \alpha b$ is an eigenvalue, $\bar{\mu} = a - \alpha b$ is another eigenvalue and both have the same algebraic multiplicity. Denoting $V(\lambda)'$ the generalized eigenspace relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, we can decompose $V \otimes L$ as $V \otimes L = \bigoplus_{\lambda_j} V(\lambda_j)'$. This is possible since the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$ is split in $L[t]$, so it admits a Jordan canonical form as $L$-matrix. For the eigenvalues belonging to $\mathbb{K}$, all $\ker(\phi - \lambda I)^j$ have the same dimensions both when seeing them as $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces and as $L$-vector spaces, so we can find a real Jordan basis for $V(\lambda)$. Regarding the eigenvalues in $L \setminus \mathbb{K}$, it can be easily proven that if $\{z_1, \dots, z_k\}$ is a Jordan basis for $V(\lambda)'$, then $\{\bar{z_1}, \dots, \bar{z_k}\}$ is a Jordan basis for $V(\bar{\lambda})'$. Moreover, there is a basis made of elements of $V$ for $ V(\lambda)' \oplus V(\bar{\lambda})'$ by noting that $\text{Re}(z) = \frac{z + \bar{z}}{2}$ and $\text{Im}(z) = \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \alpha}$. From this, it is easy to see the real and imaginary parts of the elements of the basis $\{z_1, \dots..., z_k, \bar{z_1}, \dots, \bar{z_k}\}$ form a basis.

We can now find, supposing $\mu \in L \setminus \mathbb{K}$, what is the matrix associated to $\phi$ restricted to $V(\mu)' \oplus V(\bar{\mu})'$ with respect to a real basis of a Jordan basis. I will denote the real parts of $z$ by $x$ and the imaginary ones by $y$, and let $\{z_1, \dots, z_k, \bar{z_1}, \dots, \bar{z_k}\}$ a Jordan basis for $V(\mu)' \oplus V(\bar{\mu})$.
If $z_j$ is such that $\phi (z_j) = \mu z_j$, then $$\phi(x_j) = \phi(\frac{z_j + \bar{z_j}}{2}) = \text{Re}(\mu z_j) = \frac{\mu z_j + \bar{\mu} \bar{z_j}}{2} = \text{Re}(\mu)x_j + \alpha^2 \text{Im}(\mu)y_j$$ and $$\phi (y_j) = \text{Im}(\mu z_j) = \text{Im}(\mu)x_j + \text{Re}(\mu)y_j$$
If, on the other hand, $z_j$ is such that $\phi(z_j) = \mu z_j + z_{j-1}$, we get $$\phi(x_j) = \phi(\frac{z_j + \bar{z_j}}{2}) = \frac{\mu z_j +z_{j-1} + \bar{\mu} \bar{z_j} + \bar{z_{j_1}}}{2} = \text{Re}(\mu)x_j + \alpha^2 \text{Im}(\mu)y_j + x_{j-1}$$ and $$\phi(y_j) = \text{Im}(\mu)x_j + \text{Re}(\mu)y_j + y_{j-1}$$
Then it is immediate to find the matrix representing $\phi$ restricted to $\text{Span} \{x_i, y_i \}$ wrt the basis $\{x_i, y_i \}$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 \text{Re}(\mu) & \alpha^2 \text{Im}(\mu) \\
 \text{Im}(\mu) & \text{Re}(\mu)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In our case, the eigenvalue is $\mu = \sqrt{3} = 0 + 1 \sqrt{3}$ so the matrix will be

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 \\
 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the Jordan generalized form is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    J(2, 2)       & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & J(2, 2) & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    0 & 0 & J(\sqrt{3}, 2) & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & J(\sqrt{3}, 2) & I_2  \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J(\sqrt{3}, 2)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $J(2, 2)$ is a block of size two corresponding to the eigenvalue 2, and $J(\sqrt{3}, 2)$ is the $2 x 2$ matrix written above and $I_2$ is an identity block of size $2$.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very detailed response! I will work through the details of your work later tonight.

After a quick read-through it seems to make sense: I can see the analogy with the complex numbers. 

In the final form of your matrix, would there be another three blocks corresponding to $-\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I missed the $\alpha^2$ bit.

Comment: ok, I am not really sure how hard Harvard comprehensive exams are. You really think they wanted the students to find a rational canonical form? But then they should have made that more clear, in my opinion, and not call it a Jordan canonical form. In any case, @Bundle_Time, good luck with the comprehensive exams! I had a perfect $10$ many years back at Stony Brook.

Comment: @Bundle_Time, do note though that sometimes some problems are easier than others. I kind of have a feeling the exam writers just wanted the Jordan canonical form, in the usual meaning of these terms.

Comment: @Malkoun I agree, it would be *very weird* of Harvard to ask for JCF and mean [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) instead.

Comment: @A.Γ. thanks for the comment. So the canonical form over $\mathbb{Q}$ is essentially blocks of companion matrices. I should have guessed. Thank you for the link.